# How to verify Slack Events API Request Url in ASP.Net Core Mvc application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, slack, slack-api

I'm working on Slack integration in an ASP.Net Core MVC 2 application.

I have done it for Searching and Posting messages to Slack channels. Now I'm stuck at integrating Events API in this application. Basically, at the moment I'm not able to verify my Request Url as mentioned here [Events API Subscription](https://api.slack.com/events-api#subscriptions)

Following is my action method that we have give to Slack where they will send the verification json object which will be mapped to request parameter of my action and is as follows:

```
{
"token": "Jhj5dZrVaK7ZwHHjRyZWjbDl",
"challenge": "3eZbrw1aBm2rZgRNFdxV2595E9CY3gmdALWMmHkvFXO7tYXAYM8P",
"type": "url_verification"
}

[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Event(EventsRequest request)
    {
        if (request != null)
        {
            if (request.type.Equals("url_verification"))
                return Content(request.challenge);
            else
                ViewBag.Challenge = request.challenge;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Here is my EventsRequest class:

```
public class EventsRequest
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string challenge { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

I have deployed this application locally on IIS and have applied InBound rules to make it accessible publicly and it is accessible. But issues arise when I give the following URL to Slack for verification:

> http://IP_Address/Slack/Event

Following is the screenshot of the response that Slack gives
[image]

Can someone tell what's wrong here? I tried to hit this URL with Postman and I was able to get the desired results.

Comment: I would guess the problem lies in the part of code that translates the incoming Slack request into your `EventsRequest` object. Please add the code for EventsRequest to your question

Comment: @ErikKalkoken please see the edits. Can it be possible that i have to host my project to some hosting and then it will work?

Comment: Maybe. You definitely need to make sure that the server that is running your code can be reached from the Internet, or Slack will not be able to connect to it. So it needs to either run on a webserver on the Internet or you need to open a connection to your local machine. One way of doing that is using a VPN tunnel like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). See here for a tutorial on how that works: https://api.slack.com/tutorials/tunneling-with-ngrok

Comment: I have deployed the code on IIS server in my local machine and through my network administrator i have assigned it a public IP. My application is accessible now from outside of my organization which means it should also be available to Slack.

Comment: I think I found your error: your code is assuming a standard HTTP POST form request, but Slack is sending your a JSON body. Your code is missing the de-serialization of the JSON body to your C# object.

Comment: No as shown in the attached screen shot, Slack will send HTTP POST request

Comment: yes, but there are different kinds of HTTP POST requests. A normal POST request has a body encoded in `x-www-form-urlencoded` and that is I think what your program is assuming. But Slack is sending a body encoded in JSON, which requires a different approach, e.g. JSON de-serialization. You can simulate that in Postman with: POST / Body / Raw / JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:

1. As suggested in https://api.slack.com/events-api#subscriptions

> Your Event Request URL must be confirmed before saving this form. If
>   your server takes some time to "wake up" and your initial attempt at
>   URL verification fails due to a timeout, use the retry button to
>   attempt verification again.

If it fails at first attempt make sure server is up & running and try next time.

2. > After you've completed typing your URL, we'll dispatch a HTTP POST to
   >   your request URL. We'll verify your SSL certificate and we'll send a
   >   application/json POST body containing three fields:
   >
   > `{
   >       "token": "Jhj5dZrVaK7ZwHHjRyZWjbDl",
   >       "challenge": "3eZbrw1aBm2rZgRNFdxV2595E9CY3gmdALWMmHkvFXO7tYXAYM8P",
   >       "type": "url_verification" 
   >   }`

You need to replace example json with the real values generated for you url configuration and verification.

Make sure url for verification is set correctly before generating **challenge** and is not changed afterwards.

3. Make sure no mismatch in url scheme like http in one place and https at other.

Try adding from body in post request:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Event([FromBody]EventsRequest request)
```

Comment: Can it be possible that i have to host my project to some hosting and then it will work?

Comment: I did not get you question. What is mentioned in document is that you need to first configure url(ip or working dns) then generate challenge for your url which will act as identifier for your API. Use same challenge in POST request

Comment: If challenge is verified then it will work. Make sure you configure same ip while generating config & verifying, otherwise new challenge will need to reconfigured for that URL/IP OR separate environment for dev & prod with different challenge.

Comment: Have you configured same url/IP in slack API to generate Challenge, which you are using for verification?

Comment: Yes as i have mentioned in my question that, i'm able to hit the url locally deployed on IIS. but when i try to do it with a public ip (which is accessible) it fails.

Comment: Have you selected event `url_verification` in event types when setting up slack application?

Comment: Try adding `FromBody` attribute for request parameter, I have added format in answer